# Adding keyboard controls to a Leaflet js Choropleth map

Tags: javascript, accessibility, leaflet

I have a leaflet.js choropleth map that is almost exactly like the tutorial map

http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

I want to be able to tab through the map and have the states info show up.

I have tried faking it with hidden links and triggering on the layers, but haven't had any success.

Any idea what best way to approach this would be?

Comment: Is this your code or do you have to overlay this on top of existing code?

Comment: Its different data, but implemented exactly the same as the example. http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html

Comment: I have used hidden links a triggering fake mouse events to highlight graphic elements so this is possible, you will have to post your code somewhere for me to help. On a usability note, when you have a large number of items like this, it becomes difficult for the user to navigate to the state they are interested in using the keyboard. Therefore another UI approach like a select dropdown where the first character can be used to move to the state might be more usable.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, I was able to get the mouseover to be simulated as (assuming that the variable 'p' is one of the path elements representing a state) on this page http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html

```
getScrollOffset = function (element) {
    if (!element.nodeType && element.document) {
        element = element.document;
    }
    if (element.nodeType === 9) {
        var docElement = element.documentElement,
            body = element.body;
        return {
            left: (docElement && docElement.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0),
            top: (docElement && docElement.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0)
        };
    }
    return {
        left: element.scrollLeft,
        top: element.scrollTop
    };
};

getElementCoordinates = function (element) {
    var doc = element.ownerDocument,
        scrollOffset = getScrollOffset(doc),
        xOffset = scrollOffset.left,
        yOffset = scrollOffset.top,
        coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        top: coords.top + yOffset,
        right: coords.right + xOffset,
        bottom: coords.bottom + yOffset,
        left: coords.left + xOffset,
        width: coords.right - coords.left,
        height: coords.bottom - coords.top
    };
};
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[50];
var coords = getElementCoordinates(p);
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window,
0, coords.left/* screenX */, coords.top/* screen Y */, 0 /* clientX */, 0/* clientY */, false, false, false, false, 0, document.body);
p.dispatchEvent(evt);
```